# multiple blogs on single site

Tags: blog-page

In my custom theme, I had to set one of the templates to home and then under Reading Settings set that to be the Posts Page. That allowed the site to read from the content of my home.php. And I customized it to display blog posts. However, now I want to create another blog post on the site. But the Reading Settings only allows you to select one of the pages as the Posts Page, so how can I get around that?